# A script for copying random folders

Tags: usb, bash, scripts, python, music

I'd like to realize a little project I've always had in mind. I have a vast music library on my desktop and I'm looking for a way/script to select a random amount of folders (say, 25 albums) and, if doable, copy them onto a USB drive for my car. My full vision would be a script able to do these steps:

1. Erase the USB drive (it would be used only for music)
2. Random selection of albums (data amount cap? fixed number?)
3. Copy the selection to the USB drive

Is this doable via a simple script? I remember some music organizers had this option, but I was looking for something simpler for a headless server.

Comment: I assume the folders are stored somwhere in a permanent location?

Comment: Yes, I have a dedicated hard drive for music

Comment: Nice question, will look into it if I get home. An album is a folder, containing music files?

Comment: ATM every artist has a folder with albums as subfolders, but since everything is sorted out with metadata I can easily move to a simpler, one tier structure with folders named as Artist - Album

Comment: @JacobVlijm this is really something for you i tried to solve it with bash-script and its a mess really to get a randomization there.

Comment: @Videonauth I am *aaaaaaallmost* done. Python is nice in this case I think :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm *Can* there be one, if all are correct?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju of course there can. Not suggesting *in any way* which one OP should pick, but there will probably be a favourite one. Not accepting any of the answers suggests none of them was acceptable.

Answer (score 7):

The script below should do the job:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
import os
import subprocess
import shutil

# set the desired number of folders to pick below
n_selection = 5
# set the name of the flash drive below
flashdr = "Lexar"
# set the source directory (with media folders) below
sourcedr = "/path/to/mediafiles"
# ---

try:
    targetdr = [l.split("part ")[-1] for l in subprocess.check_output("lsblk")\
                .decode("utf-8").splitlines()if l.endswith(flashdr)][0]
except IndexError:
    pass
else:
    # empty the flash drive
    for item in os.listdir(targetdr):
        obj = os.path.join(targetdr, item)
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(obj)
        except NotADirectoryError:
            os.remove(obj)
    # list the source dirs
    srclist = []
    for dr in  os.listdir(sourcedr):
        fullpath = os.path.join(sourcedr, dr)
        if os.path.isdir(fullpath):
            srclist.append([dr, fullpath])
    # copy the files
    for picked in random.sample(srclist, n_selection):
        shutil.copytree(picked[1], os.path.join(targetdr, picked[0]))
        srclist.remove(picked)
```

It copies directories from the first sub-level of the source-directory into the targeted flash drive.

This is what seems to make the most sense, since *recursively* copying folders, *at random*, causes a big difference in folder- size and number sub-levels. I added it nevertheless as a second option at the bottom of this answer.

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `create_mediausb.py`
2. In the head section, set the number of files to be selected, the *name* of the flash drive (the script will find its path) and the source diectory with folders.
3. Run the script with the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/create_mediausb.py
   ```
4. If all works fine, add it to a shortcut key: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/create_mediausb.py
   ```

#### Second option: recursive selection

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
import os
import subprocess
import shutil

n_selection = 5
flashdr = "Lexar"
sourcedr = "/home/jacob/Bureaublad/GW_site_nafestival_2015/pix/general"

try:
    targetdr = [l.split("part ")[-1] for l in subprocess.check_output("lsblk")\
                .decode("utf-8").splitlines()if l.endswith(flashdr)][0]
except IndexError:
    pass
else:
    # empty the flash drive
    for item in os.listdir(targetdr):
        obj = os.path.join(targetdr, item)
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(obj)
        except NotADirectoryError:
            os.remove(obj)
    # list the source dirs
    srclist = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sourcedr):
        for dr in dirs:
            srclist.append([dr, os.path.join(root, dr)])
    # copy the files
    for picked in random.sample(srclist, n_selection):
        shutil.copytree(picked[1], os.path.join(targetdr, picked[0]))
        srclist.remove(picked)
```

The script:

1. Looks up the path to the flash drive:

   ```py
   try:
       targetdr = [l.split("part ")[-1] for l in subprocess.check_output("lsblk")\
                   .decode("utf-8").splitlines()if l.endswith(flashdr)][0]
   except IndexError:
       pass
   ```

   If the flash drive is not found, it ends here
2. If the drive was found, it is emptied

   ```py
   # empty the flash drive
   for item in os.listdir(targetdr):
       obj = (targetdr+"/"+item)
       try:
           shutil.rmtree(obj)
       except NotADirectoryError:
           os.remove(obj)
   ```
3. Then, since we need *the whole* directory list to make an appropriate selection at random, we create a list before making the selection:

   ```py
   # list the source dirs
   srclist = []
   for dr in  os.listdir(sourcedr):
       fullpath = sourcedr+"/"+dr
       if os.path.isdir(fullpath):
           srclist.append([dr, fullpath])
   ```
4. The most interesting part is making the selection. We pick a random directory, remove it from the list to prevent double picks, then pick another one at random, remove it, and so on, until we reach the number of desired picks:

   ```py
   # copy the files
   for picked in random.sample(srclist, n_selection):
       shutil.copytree(picked[1], os.path.join(targetdr, picked[0]))
       srclist.remove(picked)
   ```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/path/to/create_mediausb.py`? I'd edit it myself, but AU says all suggested edits should be at least 6 characters.

Comment: You are incredible Jacob, I've always deeply admired you. You don't only find solutions, you offer lessons!

Comment: Some comments on your code: 1) Use `os.path.join(targetdr, xxx)` instead of just putting a `/` in there. 2) Instead of using `randint` to manually obtain a *random sample* I'd rather use the built-in [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.sample): `for picked in random.sample(srclist, n_selection): shutil.copytree(picked[1], os.path.join(targetdr, picked[0]))`

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks for mentioning! `random.sample(srclist, n_selection)` is definitely nicer. `os.path.join()` I know, but doing it this way saves a few characters. Changed it though, the second script in a minute... Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

you could use find and shuf:

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE="path/to/source"
DESTINATION="path/to/destination"
COUNT=25

rm -r "${DESTINATION}/"*
find "$SOURCE" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d|shuf -n $COUNT|xargs -d'\n' -I{} cp -r "{}" "$DESTINATION"
```

Comment: This is so much more simpler than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

I made a script with Python:

[The script, at GitHub Gist.](https://gist.github.com/bharadwaj-raju/967e9127533679f36c34a2647b0dfbcc) ([Download](https://gist.github.com/bharadwaj-raju/967e9127533679f36c34a2647b0dfbcc/raw/be67692b478ef64619b86e9a42e6271dcac0a4f7/RandomCopier.py))

**Usage:**

```
python3 RandomCopier.py [source folder] [destination folder] [number to copy]
```

**The copy method:**

**NOTE:** It will *not* copy any files directly in the source folder, only those in sub-folders of it.

Say, the source folder, `src` is:

```
src
|- a
|  |- file_a
|  |- file_a_2
|
|- b
|  |- file_b
|
|- c
|  |- file_c
|
|- file_src
```

then, the destination folder `dest` would be, with 2 folders randomly copied, like:

```
dest
|- a
|  |- file_a
|  |- file_a_2
|
|- c
|  |- file_c
```